# How to make LibGDX's AndroidApplication class support Android Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, libgdx

**My goal:** I want to use fragments along side my libgdx game on android.

Here's the problem. For an activity to host the libgdx game, it must extend the AndroidApplication class.

```
public class MyGameActivity extends AndroidApplication {}
```

Whereas AndroidApplication is also an extension of the Activity class

```
public class AndroidApplication extends Activity ... {}
```

I want to use fragments on the activity, and this is where the problem comes. I also need to make MyGameActivity extend FragmentActivity like so to support fragments

```
public class MyGameActivity extends FragmentActivity {}
```

But the game won't run if it doesn't extend AndroidApplication.
How do I get around this problem?

If only I can do this...

```
public class MyGameActivity extends AndroidApplication, FragmentActivity {}
```

I'm using the support libraries to make the app backwards compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do multiple inheritance in Java and even if you could how would it work?

What you can do is copy this code https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplication.java

in your class inherited from FragmentActivity

public class MyAndroidApplication extends FragmentActivity implements Application

And in the place where you instantiate AndroidApplication you must instantiate MyAndroidApplication.

Comment: I guess this will have to do for now. Though there are other classes which require AndroidApplication class such as the AndroidInput and AndroidAudio class, and the MyAndroidApplication won't work with them.

Comment: That's true. You probably need to create MyAndroidInput and MyAndroidAudio too. Luckily LibGdx is open source. In general, I would say that this part could be improved. I will consider possibility to fix it within couple of weeks.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** LibGdx now supports Android fragments, use AndroidFragmentApplication. See [documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Starter-classes-%26-configuration#fragment-based-libgdx)